# Passing list to a function as argument and modifying in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I have been told that when we pass a list to a function, the list is passed by reference.

So, if I have

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> def change(a):
...     a += [1]
```

The following works as expected.

```
>>> change(a)
>>> a
[0, 1]
```

But if I have the function `change` as

```
>>> def change(a):
...     a = [1]
```

and `a = [0]`. Then if I do,

```
>>> change(a)
```

The result is as following

```
>>> a
[0]
```

This means that here, the list was not passed by reference.

Is this behaviour expected? I am using Python 2.7.6

Comment: Reassignment is not the same as alteration. If you do `a = [1]` you are not altering a list; you are creating a new list. The old one is not altered.

Comment: `a = b = [1];`  Now doing `a = 2` won't affect `b`, `a` now points to a new object.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for the comments. I still do not understand why are there two different variables if one is passed by reference to a function?

Comment: I shall take a look at the already existing question.

Comment: Because you just tell `a` to reference a different area of memory containing the array `[1]`. You do not update/overwrite the original array.

Comment: The variable `a` inside the definition of `change` is a different variable from the variable `a` outside the definition of `change`. To begin with, they are referring to the same list. Then you change the one inside `change` to refer to a different list. It would be clearer if you hadn't called them both `a`.